# How to Databind a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

my questions is how to databind a datagridview using my codes below. Please check it.. thanks!

```
    InsuranceLabel oInsurance = new InsuranceLabel(); //Retrieves the list of existing Insurance from my database
    oInsurance.Name = grdInsurance.Columns(0).text; //Fields Name
    oInsurance.City = grdInsurance.Columns(0).text; //Fields City
    oInsurance.Category = grdInsurance.Columns(0).text; //Fields Category
    grdInsurance.DataSource = oInsurance;
    grdInsurance.AutoGenerateColumns = true; //not sure that's the property
    grdInsurance.DataBind();
```

i hope you can help me.. thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing **oInsurance.Name = grdInsurance.Columns(0).text;**, Are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grid View requires a collection of objects not a single object.

But as a workaround you can Create a List of IncuranceLabel then add your object to it.

```
List<IncuranceLabel> items = new List<IncuranceLabel>();
items.add(oInsurance);
grdInsurance.DataSource = items;
grdInsurance.Databind();
```

Comment: its working.. but its shows only one fields(Agency Code).. how about the Name, City, Category?

Comment: In order to make it show all the fields create a custom class that has all the fields you need and override its ToString() method so that it prints all the fields with some separator between them (inverval, newline, etc.). When you use List<YouCustomClassWithOverrideToString> items = ... everything will work fine :)

Comment: I am not sure if this code is working: 
oInsurance.Name = grdInsurance.Columns(0).text;
Could you put a static value to test like : oInsurance.Name = " Test ";

Answer (score 3):

create a Collection Class and make it as the datasource

```
grdInsurance.DataSource = CollectionClass;
grdInsurance.Databind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to design your class so properties are true properties and not fields.

For example, **dont** do :

```
// Bad example: all of these are Fields, not Properties
public class InsuranceLabel 
{
    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public string Category;
}
```

Instead, do :

```
// Good example: all of these are Properties
public class InsuranceLabel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```